# Change y range to start from 0 with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot data. Here's a code that does something similar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
xdata = [1, 4, 8]
ydata = [10, 20, 30]
ax.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.show(f)
```

This shows a line in a graph with the y axis that goes from 10 to 30. While I am satisfied with the x range, I would like to change the y range to start from 0 and adjust on the ymax to show everything.

My current solution is to do:

```
ax.set_ylim(0, max(ydata))
```

However I am wondering if there is a way to just say: autoscale but starts from 0.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The range must be set **after** the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
xdata = [1, 4, 8]
ydata = [10, 20, 30]
ax.plot(xdata, ydata)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show(f)
```

If `ymin` is changed before plotting, this will result in a range of [0, 1].

**Edit: the `ymin` argument has been replaced by `bottom`:**

```
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
```

Documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html

You can do the same on the x axis with left and right:

```
ax.set_xlim(left=0)
```

Documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html

Comment: Ah, nice. I guess even leaving the `ymax` unchanged still must turn off the autoscaling.

Comment: Exactly. And fix it to `1.0`.

Comment: or turn autoscaling off.

Comment: I'm fitting a curve and my data points star around 0.1 but I want this to start at 0.0 without affecting the fit or data.  Is there also a way to make the lines of the curve point in question go to 0?

Comment: Is there an x-axis equivalent? xlim doesnt appear to have a bottom keyword argument associated with it.

Comment: @SamuelNewport I suppose you've tried with `ax.set_xlim(left=None, right=None)`

Comment: Settled for `ax.set_xlim([0, 0.6])` The above worked with `left=0`. Thought it would make a good addition to the question for completeness since this page comes up first when googling how to change x-axis range

Answer (score 63):

Try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xdata = [1, 4, 8]
ydata = [10, 20, 30]
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)  # this line
plt.show()
```

doc string as following:

```
>>> help(plt.ylim)
Help on function ylim in module matplotlib.pyplot:

ylim(*args, **kwargs)
    Get or set the *y*-limits of the current axes.

    ::

      ymin, ymax = ylim()   # return the current ylim
      ylim( (ymin, ymax) )  # set the ylim to ymin, ymax
      ylim( ymin, ymax )    # set the ylim to ymin, ymax

    If you do not specify args, you can pass the *ymin* and *ymax* as
    kwargs, e.g.::

      ylim(ymax=3) # adjust the max leaving min unchanged
      ylim(ymin=1) # adjust the min leaving max unchanged

    Setting limits turns autoscaling off for the y-axis.

    The new axis limits are returned as a length 2 tuple.
```

Comment: This answer is preferable for me, because it's less typing, without the need to deal with `subplots`, `ax` axes objects etc.

Comment: In matplotlib 3.3, use **plt.ylim(bottom=0)**

Answer (score 14):

Note that `ymin` will be removed in Matplotlib 3.2 [Matplotlib 3.0.2 documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html).
Use `bottom` instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
xdata = [1, 4, 8]
ydata = [10, 20, 30]
ax.plot(xdata, ydata)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show(f)
```

Comment: FYI: `ymin` still works in Matplotlib 3.6.2

Answer (score 1):

The following code makes sure that the y-value 0 always appears in the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xdata = np.array([1, 4, 8])
ydata = np.array[10, 20, 30])
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(0, min(xdata)), max(0, max(xdata)), 5))
plt.show()
```

It also works for only negative y-data values. The last argument (the tick step) can be dropped.