# Is there a way to make matplotlib put zeros at origin?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I set the plot to have a xlim and ylim that isn't symmetric, I get these type of plots where there's a different number other than zero at the origin. Is there a way to force Matplotlib to have zero at the origin no matter the xlim and ylim? Thanks.

Edit 1 (The Matplot is a Widget for my PyQT5 Application):

```
    def InitUI(self):
    # move quadrant lines
    #
    self.canvas.axes.spines['left'].set_position('center')
    self.canvas.axes.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    self.canvas.axes.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    self.canvas.axes.spines['top'].set_color('none')

    # set range and grid
    #
    self.canvas.axes.set_axisbelow(True)
    self.canvas.axes.grid(which='major',color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.25, alpha=0.50)
    #self.canvas.axes.grid(which='minor',color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.25, alpha=0.50)
    self.canvas.axes.set_xlim([-3, 5])
    self.canvas.axes.set_ylim([-3, 5])

    self.canvas.axes.tick_params(labelsize=8)
    x_axis = self.canvas.axes.get_xlim()
    y_axis = self.canvas.axes.get_ylim()
    x_axis = np.linspace(x_axis[0],x_axis[1],9)
    y_axis = np.linspace(y_axis[0],y_axis[1],9)
    y_axis = y_axis[y_axis != 0]
    self.canvas.axes.set_xticks(x_axis)
    self.canvas.axes.set_yticks(y_axis)
```

[X and Y range between -3 and 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Nt2.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change y range to start from 0 with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642511/change-y-range-to-start-from-0-with-matplotlib)

Comment: You've provided an image of the output, but no example of the code that produced the output. Please share a few lines of your Python that demonstrate the issue, so that people can suggest improvement to whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: I've added the code I used to generate the image. @GurkiratSingh Unfortunately, that doesn't answer my question. I want the origin to always be at 0 but I also want Y to have any range not just start at 0.

Comment: @Shmydo have you tried setting `ax.set_xlim(xmin=0)` instead of `ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)`

Comment: @GurkiratSingh Yeah I tried it however it removes the negative Y values and X values which is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this. It seems like if change the argument 'center' in these lines:

```
self.canvas.axes.spines['left'].set_position('center')
self.canvas.axes.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
```

to:

```
self.canvas.axes.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
self.canvas.axes.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
```

It will always make sure that the zeros are at the origin.