# Smooth Approximation of KDE in python

Tags: python, seaborn, statsmodels, kde-plasma, scipy.stats

I am trying to get only non-negative values on the x-axis on the plot for my KDE. I know I can limit the x-axis values but I do not want that. Is there way to smoothly approximate the KDE such that there are no non-negative value? All my data are non-negative but I do not have a lot of sample points(max 500 and I cannot get more). I have also tried to adjust the bandwidth and its not looking nice.

```
for i in range(len(B)):
    ax = sns.kdeplot(data[i],shade=True)   
ax.set_xlabel('Maimum detection time')
ax.legend(['N=25,R=20', 'N=30,R=20', 'N=35,R=20'],fontsize=5)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot figure]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change y range to start from 0 with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642511/change-y-range-to-start-from-0-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Seaborn's kdeplot has a `clip=` parameter which might be useful. Note that getting more data would only help a bit, because a gaussian kde only supposes smooth distributions, without a cut-off.

Answer (score 4):

What goes on behind kdeplot is that a kernel density is fitted with many little normal density (see [this illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3AComparison_of_1D_histogram_and_KDE.png)) and the densities at the very edge of the truncation cutoff spill over.

Using an example data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy.stats import norm

np.random.seed(999)

data = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.exponential(0.3,100),
                     'b':np.random.exponential(0.5,100)})
```

If you use `clip=`, it doesn't stop the evaluation at negative values:

```
for i in data.columns:
    ax = sns.kdeplot(data[i],shade=True,gridsize=200)
```

[image]

If you add `cut=0`, it will look odd. As you pointed out, you can truncate it at 0:

[image]

There are two solutions proposed in this [post on cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65866/good-methods-for-density-plots-of-non-negative-variables-in-r). I write a python implementation of the R code provided by @whuber:

```
def trunc_dens(x):
    kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(x)
    kde.fit()
    h = kde.bw
    w = 1/(1-norm.cdf(0,loc=x,scale=h))
    d = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(x)
    d = d.fit(bw=h,weights=w / len(x),fft=False)
    d_support = d.support
    d_dens = d.density
    d_dens[d_support<0] = 0
    return d_support,d_dens
```

We can check how it looks for `data['a']` :

```
kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(data['a'])
kde.fit()
plt.plot(kde.support,kde.density)
_x,_y = trunc_dens(data['a'])
plt.plot(_x,_y)
```

[image]

You can plot it for both:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for i in data.columns:
    _x,_y = trunc_dens(data[i])
    ax.plot(_x,_y)
```

[image]